# It it proper to use the setcookie function inside a user defined function?

Tags: php, setcookie

Are there any reasons why I should not use the PHP setcookie function inside a user defined function?

I'm using a setcookie function for a login script. Whenever the user logs in the script calls the function and sets the cookie.

```
user_login ($login_username){
setcookie("logged_in", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
}
```

There are several examples in the PHP Manual where setcookie() is used inside user defined functions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

However, the examples are user contributed examples and not part of the official PHP Manual.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is a user defined function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're free to use `setcookie()` inside a user function.

But. In your example, there are some things that should not work :

1. the keyword `function` is missing before `user_login`.
2. the `$value` is not defined.

So it should be :

```
function user_login ($login_username){
    setcookie("logged_in", $login_username, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
}
```